# Calculating $f(x,y)=3xy +x^2$ on the unit circle

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto 3xy +x^2$

$D:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$

$\iint_Df(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}(3r^2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)+r^2\cos^2(\phi))\cdot r ~~d\phi dr=\int_0^1 \pi r^3 dr = \frac{\pi}{4}$

This solution was given to us. My problem is, that i can't see, how they figured out, that the first integral is $\pi$.

Comment: Shouldn't the $r^2\cos(\phi)$ be $r^2\cos^2(\phi)$?

Comment: Yes, of course, i've corrected it.

Comment: Now, factor out the powers of $r$, separate the remaining integral into two parts and evaluate.  You'll get $0$ for one integral and $\pi$ for the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\phi\sin\phi\,d\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(2\phi)}{2}\,d\phi=\cdots=0,$$
and
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\phi\,d\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos(2\phi)}{2}d\phi=\cdots=\pi.$$
You should be able to complete the missing steps "$\cdots$" easily. Also, recall that the $r$'s in the inner integral can be treated as *constants* since we integrate with respect to $\phi$ first.

Putting all together:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}(3r^2\cos\phi\sin\phi+r^2\cos^2\phi)r\,d\phi &=3r^3\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\phi\sin\phi\,d\phi+r^3\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\phi\,d\phi \\
&=3r^3\times 0+r^3\times\pi \\
&=\pi r^3,
\end{align}
$$
which is what you were given. We finally get
$$\iint_Df(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1\pi r^3\,dr=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: The first integral is zero ( $[-0.5cos^2(\phi)]$, the second is $[0.5(\phi +sin(\phi)cos(\phi)])$, which is $\pi$. But then i have $3r^3 \pi$ left..

Comment: @fear.xD I am not sure I understand your question, but I added some details that hopefully will clarify how to compute the integral to get the desired result.